# RNAse activity review

Tags: rna, enzymes, protein-structure

I was searching for any review unravelling the structure-function motifs responsible for RNAse activity. Or at least a well-composed review of RNAse superfamilies that are described nowadays (with linkage to their functional activity). My PubMed search performed didn't give any valuable results for that. 
Any specialists to comment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a specialist but was wondering whether your interest and expectation was motifs related to catalysis or to substrate specificity.

Comment: @David I'd rather say both. But mainly focusing on the catalytic sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a few searches, just for fun, but all I came up with was:

> Yuhong Zuo and Murray P. Deutscher "Exoribonuclease superfamilies: structural analysis and phylogenetic distribution"
>   (2001) Nucl. Acids Res. 29 (5): 1017-1026. doi: 10.1093/nar/29.5.1017

Not very recent, but it's open access. It might be possible to search for more recent papers that have cited this. Although I haven't tried it myself, I found suggestions for doing this at https://www.bc.edu/libraries/help/howdoi/howto/pubcitation.html.